# In Blazor Wasm How to load local bitmap file and Decode to SkBitmap

Tags: file, bitmap, local, webassembly

In Blazor/Wasm I have been trying to load local bitmap(*.png *.jpg) files and to decode to SKBitmap
All the local bitmap(*.png *.jpg) have been build as Embeded resource

All the below codes are not working.....Help... Many Thanks

```
    public async Task LoadBkImagesAsync()
    {
                    //this is the wwwroot/Images/BkImages/.....all the *.jpg, *.png for all bitmaps 
        Directory = "Images/";//"sample-data/weather.json"

        string DirName = Directory + "BkImages/";
        string[] SkyIDs = new string[] { "Blue3.jpg", "BlueSky2.jpg", "BlueSky2.jpg", "BlueWave.png",                 
                  "Green12.jpg", "GreenRain.jpg", "GreenYellow2.jpg", "Hsky1.jpg", nSky.jpg"};    ;
        BkImages = new SKBitmap[10] { null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null };

        string BkName;
        for (int n = 0; n < SkyIDs.Length; n++)
        {
            BkName = DirName + SkyIDs[n];

            Stream stream = await Http.GetStreamAsync( BkName );
            //below code not work
            //BkImages[n] = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
            //

            //below code not work
            //BkImages[n] = SKBitmap.Decode(BkName);
            //

            SkiaSharp.SKCodec SKCodec = SkiaSharp.SKCodec.Create( stream );
                            //below code not work
            BkImages[n] = SKBitmap.Decode( SKCodec );

        }

    }
```

All the code as above being marked "//below code not work" and tried
all the decoded SKBitmaps from Blazor Wasm local wwwroot/Images/BkImages/.....all the *.jpg, *.png file
system will be used in SkiaSharp Canvas as follow

void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
{
......
canvas.DrawBitmap(skyBmp, new SKRect(0, 0, NewInfo.Width, NewInfo.Height));
.......
}
user interactively dragging .....

I have used below code in Xamarin .... It work well for user interactively dragging .....
Taigy6789Imgs[n] = SKBitmap.Decode(ThisAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(DirName + ID6789s[n]));

Is there any other alternative to work out.. Many thanks